# Executar funções dentro de variáveis em PHP

Tags: php

Em certo projeto estou com erro ao tentar criar uma variável como função, por exemplo:

```
namespace Classes;

class Teste
{
    public static function abc() { return 'teste'; }
}
```

Ao chamar a função normalmente funciona:

```
\Classes\Teste::abc();
```

Mas quando tento:

```
   $class = "\Classes\Teste::abc";
   $class();
```

Ele retorna um erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function \Classes\Teste::abc()
```

Comment: O objetivo é so invocar o método? ou tem algo mais?

Comment: Eu preciso executar a função sendo que o nome da Classe é gerado dinamicamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro da na segunda linha pois você tenta chamar uma string(retorno de `abc()`) como uma função.
Se for apenas invocar o método pode usar função [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php), sendo o primeiro argumento a função/método e o segundo os seus argumentos. Para chamar métodos com mais argumentos use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
 <?php
class Teste
{
    public static function abc() {
        return 'teste';
    }

    public static function soma($a, $b){
        return $a+$b;
    }

}

$class = "Teste::abc";
echo call_user_func($class) .'<br>';

$str_metodo = "Teste::soma";
echo call_user_func_array($str_metodo, array(30,1));
```

[phpfiddle - exemplo](https://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5nv3-zcra)